# The constructor Restaurant.DBHelper(Restaurant) is undefined

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection

I followed the tutorial where I need to connect SQLite database into eclipse. But somehow I always get this error and I had pt this in it but it still having error all the time?

```
public Restaurant open() throws SQLException
{
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

this is the link I followed : http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

```
 public class Restaurant {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_DETAIL = "detail";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Restaurantdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="Food";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.restaurant.sesame/databases/";

private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private final Context ourContext;
private DBHelper ourHelper;


public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private final Context myContext;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{


            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }


    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(ourDatabase != null)
                ourDatabase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



}
public Restaurant(Context c)
{   
    ourContext = c;
}

public Restaurant open() throws SQLException
{
    ***ourHelper = new DBHelper(this);***


    try {

        ourHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

    ourHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

}
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: it seems you comment out the constructor.

Comment: I didnt comment it out. It is normal in my eclipse.

Comment: ![this is my com screenshot][1] [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY504.png

Comment: check with the ddms whether your database is created or nor as you have not used the oncreate method.

Comment: ddms? Where can I find it? I created a database named Restaurantdb ad store it in the assets folder.

Comment: but "/data/data/com.restaurant.sesame/databases/ says you have this path ddms is in eclipse.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html follow this tutorial it will be a great help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify right context. I bet the contructor is looking for argument like:

`new DBHelper(MyActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

well of course you will get that error ...you have commented out the constructor of the DBHelper class and the compiler can't find it when you call the constructor...

check these tutorials http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6   ....they will guide you step by step as to how to set up the connection with the database

hope this helps